# design patterns for transactional services with checkpoints and recovery

Tags: design-patterns, transactions, recovery, fault-tolerance, checkpoint

I have a multistep process where each step does some network IO (web service call) and then persists some data. I want to design it in a fault tolerant way so that if the service fails, either because of a system crash or one of the steps fails, I am able to recover and re-start from the last error free step.

Here is how I am thinking of addressing this (this is pretty high level):

1. Stored the state of each step (NOT_STARTED, IN_PROGRESS, FAILED) in a database table
2. If a step fails mark it and its dependent step as "FAILED" and move to the next non dependent step
3. Recover by reading this table (e.g in a bootstrap portion of the application)

I was wondering if there are some design patterns, frameworks and algorithms that address this problem.

Comment: Do you feel any of the answers below accurately answer your question? If not, please try to clarify your question, so a more accurate answer can be given.

Comment: @Ari, I was looking more in the direction of algorithms, frameworks or design patterns (beyond basic OO stuff) that address this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice paper, "[Design patterns for checkpoint based recovery](http://www.nokia.com/library/files/docs/Design_Patterns_for_Checkpoint-Based_Rollback_Recovery.pdf)", that addresses the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider the Chain Of Responsibility Design Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Answer (score 0):

[Memento](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/memento.html) (GoF) could be used to store the state before a potentially failing call.

One good keyword to search for would be [transactions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/autp5.aspx#Data%20Transaction%20Patterns9). That allows you to roll-back changes that occurred on account of a failure to the nearest "stable" state. This is one thing your DB would be providing.

The [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) also has known uses of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of behavioral design patterns, I would recommend looking into the following, as they seem well equipped for your needs. Keep in mind that this list is based off of a very high-level understanding of your implementation.

- [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) - For defining program skeletons
- [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - For swapping algorithms as needed
- [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) - For restoring objects to their previous states
- [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) - Coupled with the memento patterns

If you're not already familiar, I would **STRONGLY** recommend looking up the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) and [Model-View-Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) patterns, as they will make your development experience much more enjoyable.

If you have any followup questions, feel free to ask. :)